# How to select a neighbouring node from within an arrow function?

Tags: javascript

The JS and HTML [at this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4v0zcgLe/1/) and shown below is part of a settings menu, which is a list of URLs and an 'x' button next to each. This is part of my fork of [this RSS app](https://github.com/zserge/headline), so not something I'm building from scratch. In practice it looks like:

```
x foo.com
x bar.com/rss
x baz.com/feed
```

The `renderSettings()` function injects data from a JSON array into the `<template id="settings-feed-item">` div, which is why nothing shows up in the JSFiddle preview. That function also adds the `onclick` functionality to every instance of the `#remove` div.

Aside from other code I've trimmed out for brevity, I want to apply CSS styling to a `#feedurl` when the `#remove` next to it is clicked.

The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to select the `#feedurl`. I've tried `this.` and the `closest()` method but I can't select it. Everything I've tried so far gets me `TypeError: undefined is not an object` in the console. What am I missing?

##### HTML

```html
<section id="feedsection">
  <ul id="feeds">
    <template id="settings-feed-item">
      <li>
        <a id="remove">x&emsp;</a><span id="feedurl"></span><a></a>
      </li>
    </template>
  </ul>
</section>
```

##### JS

```js
// RENDER SETTINGS MENU
function renderSettings() {
  keywords.value = state.keywords;
  newsFeeds.innerHTML = '';
  state.feeds.forEach(f => {
    const el = document.importNode(feedItem.content, true).querySelector('li');
    el.querySelector('span').innerText = simplifyLink(f.url);
    // ...
    // onclick `#remove`
    el.querySelectorAll('a')[0].onclick = () => {
      // SELECT URL NEXT TO CLICKED X
    };
    // ...
  });
}
```

Comment: `closest()` looks for the closest parent, not a neighbor.

Comment: Why do you have an empty anchor `<a></a>`?

Comment: If you use an arrow function for an event listener, `this` isn't set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the next sibling.

```
    el.querySelectorAll('a')[0].onclick = (e) => {
      e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.classList.add('someclass');
    };
```

BTW, IDs are supposed to be unique, so you shouldn't duplicate `id="feedurl"` in copy. Use classes instead of IDs.